# HttpApi with AWS::ApiGatewayV2::integration how to overwrite response body

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I want to overwrite the response body sent from this integration. I was referring to this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-parameter-mapping.html

It says to use `overwrite:$response.body`. But This does not work. I gives Error saying "Invalid Destination parameter"

```yaml
APIVersionIntegration:
  Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
  Properties:
    ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
    ConnectionType: INTERNET
    CredentialsArn: !GetAtt MyHttpApiRole.Arn
    IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
    RequestParameters:
      MessageBody: "$request.body"
      QueueUrl: !Ref DataPublisherSQS
    ResponseParameters:
      "200":
        ResponseParameters:
          - Source: "application/json"
            Destination: "overwrite:header.content-type"
          - Source: ""
            Destination: "overwrite:$response.body"
    IntegrationSubtype: "SQS-SendMessage"
    # IntegrationMethod: POST
    PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem (integration with SQS and I want to return an empty JSON).

Reading the documentation, it looks like there no way to override response body, only headers and status code can be modified: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-parameter-mapping.html#http-api-mapping-response-parameters

[image: Response parameter mapping keys]

Maybe the only way is to wrap SQS message sending within Lambda